# Populate SQL database from textfile on a background thread constantly

Tags: sql-server, file, background-process

Currently, I would like provide this as an option to the user when storing data to the database.

Save the data to a file and use a background thread to read data from the textfile to SQL server.

Flow of my program: 
- A stream of data coming from a server constantly (100 per second).
- want to store the data in a textfile and use background thread to copy data from the textfile back to the SQL database constantly as another user option.

Has this been done before?

Cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry your question is a bit confusing. Do you want to allow users to save data from SQL to Text files, or the opposite? and what do you mean by 100 per second? 100 files? 100 lines? please explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is indeed a bit confusing.

I'm guessing you mean that:

- 100 rows per second come from a certain source or server (eg. log entries)
- One option for the user is *textfile caching*: the rows are stored in a textfile and periodically an incremental copy of the contents of the textfile into (an) SQL Server table(s) is performed.
- Another option for the user is *direct insert*: the data is stored directly in the database as it comes in, with no textfile in between.

Am I right?

If yes, then you should do something in the lines of:

- Create a trigger on an `INSERT` action to the table
- In that trigger, check which user is inserting. If the user has *textfile caching* disabled, then the insert can go on. Otherwise, the data is redirected to a textfile (or a caching table)
- Create a stored procedure that checks the caching table or text file for new data, copies the new data into the real table, and deletes the cached data.
- Create an SQL Server Agent job that runs above stored procedure every minute, hour, day...

Since the interface from T-SQL to textfiles is not very flexible, I would recommend using a caching table instead. Why a textfile?

And for that matter, why cache the data before inserting it into the table? Perhaps we can suggest a better solution, if you explain the context of your question.

Comment: Yes.. You got the question right.
Sorry for the confusion.
Are there any examples how i can do this? I am very new to SQL especially triggers.

I won't mind using caching table if it's more effiecient.

Thanks